# How do I combine a timezone aware date and time in Python?

Tags: python, timezone, pytz

I have a date and a time that I'm attempting to combine in Python.  The time is timezone aware.

However, when I try and combine them, I get the wrong time.

```
import pytz
from datetime import time, date
NYC_TIME = pytz.timezone('America/New_York')

start_date = date(2012, 7, 7)
start_time = time(hour = 0, tzinfo = NYC_TIME)
combined = datetime.combine(start_date, start_time)
print combined
print NYC_TIME.normalize(combined)
```

This prints `2012-07-07 00:00:00-05:00`, which normalizes to `2012-07-07 01:00:00-04:00`.  Why is this happening?  How can I avoid it?

Comment: I assume by "avoid it" you want the local time to remain fixed even if the UTC offset changes due to Daylight Saving?

Comment: I was expecting, if I have a time `MIDNIGHT = time(hour = 0, tzinfo = NYC_TIME)`, that it would remain midnight no matter what date I slotted it into.  Apparently, that is not the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A time without a date attached must assume it's not in the Daylight Saving period. Once you attach a date to it, that assumption can be corrected. The zone offset changes, and the time changes as well to keep it at the same UTC equivalent.

Comment: That's strange, since if you compare two timezone-aware times that don't have a static offset, they raise a naive timezone error—that is, they refuse to assume anything about whether they're in Daylight Savings or not.